# Auto populate a table that has formulas in it to only show items with quantities greater than 0

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, datatables

I'm an electrical contractor and I made a worksheet to help me bid projects. Say I'm bidding on wiring a new house. I have broken down each task "outlet"/"Switch" to materials and labor needed for each task. Those materials are then multiplied by the quantity needed and populate 3 different tables automatically.

Here is the process: (24 outlets are needed for this job)

["Bid Cut Sheet" - Where quantities of specific tasks are entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSbaE.png)

["Job List" - Tasks are broken down into materials needed for that task, multiplied by the quantity entered in "Bid Cut Sheet"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkT6F.png)

["Material Sheet" Total of all material needed for the job in 3 different tables/stages of the project. Each quantity row "Rough" "Trim" "Service" has a formula to add the materials specified in the "Job List"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzhqq.png)

What I am trying to do is populate rows in EACH table in "Material Sheet" with quantities of materials needed. Essentially consolidate the data in EACH table by eliminating with quantities of 0 and ADDING rows with quantities >0 and fill down rows with material needed: updating every time data is entered in the "Bid Cut Sheet"

The following code does eliminate the rows with 0 in each table after the code is ran. But it does not update and ADD line items when different material is needed  for a different task entered in the "Bid Cut Sheet"

```
Sub DeleteRowsBasedonCellValue()
    'Declare Variables
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, Row As Variant
    Dim listObj As ListObject
    Dim tblNames As Variant, tblName As Variant
    Dim colNames As Variant, colName As Variant
                    'Names of tables
    tblNames = Array("Rough_Material", "Trim_Material", "Service_Material")
    colNames = Array("Rough", "Trim", "Service")
                    
    
    'Loop Through Tables
    For i = LBound(tblNames) To UBound(tblNames)
        tblName = tblNames(i)
        colName = colNames(i)
        Set listObj = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MaterialSheet").ListObjects(tblName)
        'Define First and Last Rows
        LastRow = listObj.ListRows.Count
        'Loop Through Rows (Bottom to Top)
        For Row = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            With listObj.ListRows(Row)
                If Intersect(.Range, _
                listObj.ListColumns(colName).Range).Value = 0 Then
                    .Delete
                End If
            End With
        Next Row
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the .Change event. This triggers the code you enter inside this sub-procedure every time something changes in a determined range:

[Change event - Learn Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)

Looks like you could `Call DeleteRowsBasedonCellValue()` in the .Change event in your specific range of cells to monitor inside the Bid Cut sheet, so that your desired update happens.

Comment: Hello @fran - How would this be written in the code? I am very new to all of this

Comment: On the VB Editor, click on the Microsoft Excel Objects (Above Modules) and select worksheet that you want to track changes. then, on the code editor, you can find two dropdowns above, one says (General) and the other says (Declarations). Hit the one on the left and select "Worksheet". A sub "Worksheet_SelectionChange" will be generated. Ignore or delete. Then, hit the dropdown at the right and select "Change". another sub will be generated, this is the one that should call your procedure. You can set the target cell to track in the link on my answer. Please let me know if you've got doubts,